# Как получить сообщение, которое отправил сам бот?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть бот в Telegram, в него из определенного источника приходят сообщения, от имени бота. Моя задача получить это сообщение и переслать его в приватный телеграм канал.

Вот код

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = "n"
CHANNEL_ID = '-n'

# Configure Logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def all_msg_handler(message: types.Message):  # сама пересылка
    button_text = message.text  # сообщение человека
    logger.debug("The answer is %r", button_text)

    await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, message.forward_sender_name)  # отправляем в наш канал тот самый текст
```

Как это сделать с помощью aiogram?

apt. После получение сообщения бота, нужно отправить его в канал. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
msg_bot = await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, message.forward_sender_name)
```

UPD1. Пересылка(копирование) в другой чат

```
msg_bot = await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, message.forward_sender_name)  
await msg_bot.copy_to(chat_id=CHAT_ID)
```

Comment: Как после получения отправить это в канал. Я пишу так(наверное не правильно)
    msg_bot = await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, message.forward_sender_name)
    await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, msg_bot)

Comment: @Андрей обновил ответ, юзайте copy_to